# Error converting delf to tensorflow js web

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm following this [1] and trying to convert this [2] to tensorflow js with [0]. I run into [3]. Any chance anyone knows what's going on?

[0]
tensorflowjs_converter
  --input_format=tf_hub
  'https://tfhub.dev/google/delf/1'
  delf
[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-savedmodel-keras-h5-session-bundle-frozen-model-or-tensorflow-hub-module-to-a-web-friendly-format
[2] https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/delf/1
[3]

Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-08-21 17:49:34.351121: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Creating a model with inputs [u'score_threshold', u'image', u'image_scales', u'max_feature_num'] and outputs [u'module_apply_default/NonMaxSuppression/Gather/GatherV2_1', u'module_apply_default/NonMaxSuppression/Gather/GatherV2_3', u'module_apply_default/postprocess_1/pca_l2_normalization', u'module_apply_default/Reshape_4', u'module_apply_default/truediv_2', u'module_apply_default/NonMaxSuppression/Gather/GatherV2', u'module_apply_default/ExpandDims'].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorflowjs_converter", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/goto/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 286, in main
    strip_debug_ops=FLAGS.strip_debug_ops)
  File "/Users/goto/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/tf_saved_model_conversion.py", line 420, in convert_tf_hub_module
    graph = load_graph(frozen_file, ','.join(output_node_names))
  File "/Users/goto/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/tf_saved_model_conversion.py", line 63, in load_graph
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
  File "/Users/goto/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/goto/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 422, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Input 0 of node module_apply_default/while/resnet_v1_50/conv1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp/Enter was passed float from module/resnet_v1_50/conv1/weights:0 incompatible with expected resource.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the tensorflowjs_converter are you using? My guess is that the DELF model uses some Ops which are unsupported by TFJS. The latest version of the TFJS converter should give clearer error messages about unsupported ops if that is in fact the issue.

Not all TensorFlow Hub modules are TFJS compatible. In particular, there are some Ops which are not implemented in TFJS and so the modules cannot be converted. You can find a list of supported TFJS Ops [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/master/docs/supported_ops.md)

You can try updating to the latest version of the TFJS converter to get a better error message and update TFJS to see if more of the ops are supported in a more recent version. Otherwise, you can search for open features requests or file a new one [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues) to request the Op be supported.

Comment: From source, I get the following

  File "/Users/goto/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 422, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Input 0 of node module_apply_default/while/resnet_v1_50/conv1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp/Enter was passed float from module/resnet_v1_50/conv1/weights:0 incompatible with expected resource.